# Import SDMX data by using links with Python

Tags: python, import, sdmx

Good afternoon,

I'm a student in internship. It is based on Machine Learning and I have to collect data from the Istat website "https://esploradati.istat.it/databrowser/#/it/dw/categories". However, when I want to collect them using Python, I have two SDMX links : one about the structure of the dataset and another one about the data.

To give something more practical: for example I want to import in a Python object (let's call it df) using the Query SDMX links available, this data frame:

https://esploradati.istat.it/databrowser/#/en/dw/categories/IT1,POP,1.0/POP_POPULATION/DCIS_POPRES1/IT1,22_289_DF_DCIS_POPRES1_1,1.0

In fact, I would like to have some Python lines to import this dataframe to do some statistical operations on it after. The links available are :

Structure Query:
https://esploradati.istat.it/SDMXWS/rest/dataflow/IT1/22_289_DF_DCIS_POPRES1_1/1.0/?detail=Full&references=Descendants

Data Query:
https://esploradati.istat.it/SDMXWS/rest/data/IT1,22_289_DF_DCIS_POPRES1_1,1.0/A.....99/ALL/?detail=full&dimensionAtObservation=TIME_PERIOD

I have looked for a lot of documentation on the subject but nothing helped me.
Thanks in advance for considering my request.